# DELETE WHERE AND not functioning as expected

Tags: php, sql, where-clause, sql-delete

I am attempting to delete rows from a databases. The `DELETE` query is checking for a match in date from an array and that `reason` is empty. My code is;

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'connection.php';
include 'DateTest.php';
$deleted = array();
$size = sizeof($dayOfTheWeek) - 1;

for ($count = 0; $count <= $size; $count++) {

$query = "DELETE FROM daysoff WHERE DATE(start) = '$dateMonthYearArr[$count]' AND reason = ''";               
mysql_query($query) or die("im dead1");  

$deleted[] = "Rota deleted for ". $dateMonthYearArr[$count] .".</br>";

}   $_SESSION['delete'] = $deleted;
header('Location: '. $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ;

?>
```

This `DELETE` query is dying, if I remove one of the `WHERE` arguments, either one, it works, but the `AND` seems to be an issue. Where is this failing?

Comment: Enclose in `{}` as `{$dateMonthYearArr[$count]}` Otherwise, the complex variable may not have been correctly interpolated in the double-quoted string. Did you `echo $query` to see what it looks like?

Comment: Much better though would be to [use a `foreach` loop](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) `foreach ($dayOfTheWeek as $d) { }`  C-style incremental `for` loops are not too often needed in PHP. You are almost always better served with a `foreach`.

Comment: Change `'$dateMonthYearArr[$count]'` into `'".$dateMonthYearArr[$count]."'` just like you did with `$deleted[] =`, why did you switch it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$query = "DELETE FROM daysoff WHERE DATE(start) = '" . $dateMonthYearArr[$count] . "' AND reason = ''";
```

And see how it goes...